# How to set the window's Y middle to element's Y middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a button which should shift the window's Y to "BOX - 5" `div's` Y middle through `onclick`. So in other words I want to set the "Box - 5" `div` in the middle of the window. I have tried many methods using `window.scrollTo` and using `elements.innerHeight/2`, but I still cannot center the element to the middle of the window/screen. Please Help.

I wish to only use `Javascript`, but if its not possible with it then I would accept `jQuery` script.

`index.html:`

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    current = 0;

for (var y=0;y<10;y++) {
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    box.id = "box";
    box.innerHTML = "Box - " + (y+1);
    content.appendChild(box);
}

document.querySelector("BUTTON").onclick = function() {
    var box_5 = document.querySelectorAll("#box")[4];
    /*
        NEED HELP HERE
    */
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#box {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5% auto 5% auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: black 1px solid;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>CLICK TO SET THE WINDOW'S Y MIDDLE TO (BOX 5)'s Y MIDDLE</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your snippet as below. You can use DOM element property `offsetTop` to check its Y position and use `window.scroll` to scroll the view to that element. Another sidenote, it's better to not assign the same `id` to multiple elements, so I change the id property to class and added identifier `_{index}` for the class name.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

var content = document.getElementById("content"),
    current = 0;

for (var y=0;y<10;y++) {
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    box.className += "box _" + (y+1);
    box.innerHTML = "Box - " + (y+1);
    content.appendChild(box);
}

document.querySelector("BUTTON").onclick = function() {
    var box_5 = document.querySelectorAll(".box._5")[0];
    if (box_5) {
        // scroll the window view to the element
        window.scroll({
            top: box_5.offsetTop,
            behavior: 'smooth',
        }) 
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5% auto 5% auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: black 1px solid;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>CLICK TO SET THE WINDOW'S Y MIDDLE TO (BOX 5)'s Y MIDDLE</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```